# EGL working on Linux but not on Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I have EGL/GLES 2.0 code, which I try to run on Linux (via Mesa) and Android (iOS to come). On Linux it works fine and renders like expected.
Running on Android (Phone, tablet and emulator - all 4.01) it passes fine but displays nothing (screen stays black). 
The code is 99% the same for all 3 - with some special handling for Android.
Following my EGL attributes:

```
EGLint attribList[] =
{
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,   EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
    EGL_RED_SIZE,       8,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE,     8,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE,      8,
    //EGL_ALPHA_SIZE,     (flags & ES_WINDOW_ALPHA) ? 8 : EGL_DONT_CARE,
    //EGL_DEPTH_SIZE,     (flags & ES_WINDOW_DEPTH) ? 8 : EGL_DONT_CARE,
    //EGL_STENCIL_SIZE,   (flags & ES_WINDOW_STENCIL) ? 8 : EGL_DONT_CARE,
    EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, (flags & ES_WINDOW_MULTISAMPLE) ? 1 : 0,
    // For Android this is extremely important - eglCreateContext will fail without it
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
    EGL_NONE, EGL_NONE
};
```

Following the EGL creation code:

```
EGLint numConfigs;
EGLint majorVersion;
EGLint minorVersion;
EGLDisplay display;
EGLContext context;
EGLSurface surface;
EGLConfig config;
EGLint contextAttribs[] = { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE, EGL_NONE };

// Get Display
display = eglGetDisplay((EGLNativeDisplayType)x_display);
if ( display == EGL_NO_DISPLAY )
{
  esLogMessage("eglGetDisplay failed %d\n", eglGetError());
   return EGL_FALSE;
}

// Initialize EGL
if ( !eglInitialize(display, &majorVersion, &minorVersion) )
{
  esLogMessage("eglInitialize failed %d\n", eglGetError());
   return EGL_FALSE;
}

static const size_t CONFIG_COUNT = 128;
EGLConfig configs[CONFIG_COUNT];

// Get configs
if ( !eglGetConfigs(display, configs, CONFIG_COUNT, &numConfigs) )
{
  esLogMessage("eglGetConfigs failed %d\n", eglGetError());
   return EGL_FALSE;
}
else if( numConfigs == 0 )
{
   esLogMessage("eglGetConfigs found no configs for the display\n");
   return EGL_FALSE;
}

EGLint chosenConfigCount = 0;
// Choose config
if ( !eglChooseConfig(display, attribList, &config, 1, &chosenConfigCount) )
{
  esLogMessage("eglChooseConfig failed %d\n", eglGetError());
   return EGL_FALSE;
}
else if( chosenConfigCount == 0 )
{
   esLogMessage("eglChooseConfig found no matching configs (%d available)\n", numConfigs);
   return EGL_FALSE;
}

EGLint format;
/* EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID is an attribute of the EGLConfig that is
 * guaranteed to be accepted by ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry().
 * As soon as we picked a EGLConfig, we can safely reconfigure the
 * ANativeWindow buffers to match, using EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID. */
if( !eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format) )
{
   esLogMessage("eglGetConfigAttrib failed %d\n", eglGetError());
   return EGL_FALSE;
}

#ifdef ANDROID

if( ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(hWnd, 0, 0, format) )
{
   esLogMessage("ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry failed\n");
   return EGL_FALSE;
}

#endif

// Create a surface
surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, (EGLNativeWindowType)hWnd, NULL);
if ( surface == EGL_NO_SURFACE )
{
   esLogMessage("eglCreateWindowSurface failed %d\n", eglGetError());
   return EGL_FALSE;
}

// Create a GL context
context = eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextAttribs );
if ( context == EGL_NO_CONTEXT )
{
   esLogMessage("eglCreateContext failed %d\n", eglGetError());
   return EGL_FALSE;
}   

// Make the context current
if ( !eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context) )
{
  esLogMessage("eglMakeCurrent failed %d\n", eglGetError());
   return EGL_FALSE;
}
```

Could someone shed a light, what to test or how to find the problem?

EDIT:

I fixed some other bugs and it now works fine in the Android Emulator and *HP Touchpad* (Cyanogenmod 9 alpha) but still leads to a black screen on my *Samsung Galaxy S1* with *Cyanogenmod 9* *sigh*.

Comment: Are you using real android device or emulator ? If emulator, this link could helps you : http://www.androidng.com/how-to-boost-speedup-android-emulator

Comment: What is 'x_display'? You typically want to pass EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY to eglGetDisplay().

Comment: @MartinNordholts x_display is `EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY`.

Comment: To follow up on @Tim 's comment, have you tried using eglGetError without relying on any other conditions?

ie. if(eglGetError() != EGL_SUCCESS) { esLogMessage(...) }

Some of those objects can 'successfully' initialise but throw errors regardless.

Comment: @Rushyo Can you verify your claim? If that is the case it seems to me either the API or the implementation is broken. That said - I am currently trying to implement more glGetError handling (which is indeed largely missing).

Comment: @LCIDFire I said 'can' - not 'does', although OUT_OF_MEMORY should cause plenty of fun behaviour, the spec explicitly disavows assumptions regarding method behaviour under that exception. Regardless: "[t]he action of the GL in the presence of errors is subject to change." There's simply no strong contract that defines that's how GL is going to behave.

Comment: there is no good support for EGL/OpenGL in the emulator, also the problem is that the emulator itself only provides a wrapper to the GL and GLES libraries on your machine, the work needs to be done by your GPU and your drivers which are something that is not really that good at the moment. You should test this only with real devices and official ROMs.

Comment: The open source [`cocos2d-x`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) game engine is portable for Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Android, iOS, and more. It uses EGL and OpenGL ES. You may find their source code useful!

Answer (score 0):

First, just a remark: you don't need two `EGL_NONE` to end your attribute definitions.

Second, your issue comes from the fact that `eglGetConfigs()` returns the available configs, but `eglChooseConfig(...,1,..)` will not necessarily return the config that exactly matches the one you requested.
Thus, you have to scan the configs to find the closest to your needs.

You have to call `eglGetConfigAttrib()` to compare, for instance, `EGL_RED_SIZE`, `EGL_GREEN_SIZE`,`EGL_BLUE_SIZE`, `EGL_ALPHA_SIZE`, `EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE`, `EGL_DEPTH_SIZE`, `EGL_STENCIL_SIZE`.

See [eglChooseConfig()](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/) for further details.